Setup Firebase Admin SDK with mixed Credentials (because of IID server usage)
I am building a java backend that manages subscription of devices to firebase topics, and send messages to these topics.
I am using the official sdk firebase-admin-java 9.2.0 for this.
My company wants to avoid the use of service account json files at all cost and heavily relies on ADC as we are running on K8S in gcloud.

For sending messages to topics, with proper setup on the K8S/gcloud this works fine, but, the subscription relies on the API of the instance id server (iid).
Even if the docs says that this API is deprecated, it also says that

The server-side topic management API is still available.

So I guess it is not in the same migration batch than the firebase httpv1 and it is still the relevant API to use to subscribe a token to a topic ;)

Unfortunately,

this endpoint expects a token for authentication, and seems to
not leverage ADC automatic mechanisms.
Manual credentials management involves generating a private key.
I see no another way in the GitHub official repository, and the 9.3.0 offers no
updates on this.

Building the FirebaseApp via the SDK expects only one set of credentials.
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseOptions.builder()
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
    // OR 
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
.build()

As this will be embedded in a heavily multi-tenants application (i.e. multiple firebase project), suddenly having to generate tons of private keys and managing them securely, instead on relying on the infrastructure (i.e. ADC0 which is versioned, will be a tough pill to swallow and a tough stance to take.

Is there any way to "mix" credentials? Am I missing something on the topic subscription part? Is there a new API version that does not rely on manual credential management?

